# Can we have dirty data on l1 cache in gpu?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I've read some of the common write policies in the microarchitecture of GPUs. For most of the GPU the written policy is the same as the below picture (the picture is from [the gpgpu-sim manual](http://gpgpu-sim.org/manual/index.php/Main_Page#L1_Data_Cache)). based on the below picture I have a question. can we have dirty data on the l1 cache?

[image: L1 data cache write policy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L1 on some GPU architectures [is a write-back cache](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cache-data-invalidation-between-kernel-calls/26838/5) for global accesses. Note that this topic varies by GPU architecture, e.g. for whether global activity is cached in L1.

Speaking generally, then, yes you can have dirty data.  By this I mean that the data in the L1 cache is modified (compared to what is otherwise in global space or the L2 cache) and it has not yet been "flushed" or updated into the L2 cache.  (You can also have "stale" data - data in the L1 that has not been modified, but is not consistent with the L2.)

We can create a simple proof point for this (dirty data).

The following code, when executed on a cc7.0 device (and probably some other archtectures as well) will not give the expected answer of 1024.

This is due to the fact that the L1, which is a separate entity per SM, is not immediately flushed to the L2.  It therefore has "dirty data" by the above definition.

(The code is broken for this reason.  Don't use this code.  It's just a proof point.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

constexpr int num_blocks = 1024;
constexpr int num_threads = 32;

struct Lock {
  int *locked;

  Lock() {
    int init = 0;
    cudaMalloc(&locked, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(locked, &init, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  }

  ~Lock() {
    if (locked) cudaFree(locked);
    locked = NULL;
  }

  __device__ __forceinline__ void acquire_lock() {
    while (atomicCAS(locked, 0, 1) != 0);
  }

  __device__ __forceinline__ void unlock() {
    atomicExch(locked, 0);
  }
};

__global__ void counter(Lock lock, int *total) {
  if (threadIdx.x == 1) {
    lock.acquire_lock();
    *total = *total + 1;
//    __threadfence();  uncomment this line to fix
    lock.unlock();
  }
}

int main() {
  int *total_dev;
  cudaMalloc(&total_dev, sizeof(int));
  int total_host = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(total_dev, &total_host, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  {
  Lock lock;
  counter<<<num_blocks, num_threads>>>(lock, total_dev);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemcpy(&total_host, total_dev, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  std::cout << total_host << std::endl;
  }
  cudaFree(total_dev);
}
```

In case there is any further doubt about whether this is a proper proof (e.g. to dispel arguments about things being "optimized into a register" etc.) we can study the resultant sass code.  The end of the above kernel has code that looks like this:

```
    /*0130*/                   LDG.E.SYS R0, [R4] ;                           /* 0x0000000004007381 */
                               // load *total                                               /* 0x000ea400001ee900 */
    /*0140*/                   IADD3 R7, R0, 0x1, RZ ;                        /* 0x0000000100077810 */
                               // add 1                                               /* 0x004fd00007ffe0ff */
    /*0150*/                   STG.E.SYS [R4], R7 ;                           /* 0x0000000704007386 */
                               // store *total                                               /* 0x000fe8000010e900 */
    /*0160*/                   ATOMG.E.EXCH.STRONG.GPU PT, RZ, [R2], RZ ;     /* 0x000000ff02ff73a8 */
                               //lock.unlock                                               /* 0x000fe200041f41ff */
    /*0170*/                   EXIT ;
```

Since the result register has definitely been stored to the global space, we can infer that if another thread (in another SM) reads an unexpected value in global space for `*total` it must be due to the fact that the store from another SM has not reached the L2, i.e. has not reached device-wide consistency/coherency.  Therefore the data in some other SM is "dirty".  We can (presumably) rule out the "stale" case here (the data in the other L1 *was* written, but I have "old" data in my L1) because the global load indicated above does not happen until the lock is acquired in the SM.

Note that the above code "fails" on cc7.0 devices (and probably some other device architectures).  It does not necessarily fail on the GPU you are using.  But it is still "broken".